# forceUpdate is not re-rendering children

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using the react, redux react-router stack for my webapp. In the top level component's(the component that renders on the root path) `componentDidMount` I'm subscribing to the store as shown below

```
import NotificationsList from './components/notifier';
import React from 'react';

let Spinner = ({
    isVisible,
    showSpinner,
    solidBackdrop
}) => (
    <div style={{opacity: solidBackdrop ? 1 : 0.5}} className={"spinner " + (isVisible ? '' : 'hide')}></div>
);

export default class AppPage extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        store: React.PropTypes.object,
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    handleDismissNotification(notification) {
        this.context.store.dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE_NOTIFICATION',
            data: notification
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.context.store.subscribe(() => this.forceUpdate());
    }

    render() {
        let state = this.context.store.getState();
        let props = {
            notifications: state.notifications,
            handleDismiss: this.handleDismissNotification.bind(this)
        };
        return (
            <div className="'apppage-container">
                {this.props.children}
                <NotificationsList {...props} />
                <Spinner isVisible={state.initialFetchInProgress || state.requestInProgress}
                         showSpinner={!state.initialFetchInProgress} solidBackdrop={state.initialFetchInProgress}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`this.props.children` here renders the component shown below

```
import Header from './components/header';
import React from 'react';

class ContentPage extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        store: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    render() {
        let user = this.context.store.getState().user;
        return <div className="content-container">
            <Header user/>
        </div>
    }
}

export default ContentPage;
```

The problem is that when the first time a render happens, everything goes fine. Then when the render happens through `forceUpdate`, the child component is not getting re-rendered.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with react, but I believe you will need to provide the contents of your store in order to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Every container component should be subscribed to the store separately. So accordingly, ContentPage should also have

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.context.store.subscribe(() => this.forceUpdate());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you replied to [yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034446/2502814), indeed the container component should subscribe to the store , but in addition to the subscription, it's good practice for the the container to also **un**subscribe when **un**mounted :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.context.store.subscribe(() => this.forceUpdate());
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```